# Raspberry Pi Camera Module

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to do object detection with OpenCV. Using code from pyimagesearch : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/18/real-time-object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/

Trying to run the module only for ""person detection"" instead of all the classes mentioned in the code and i get a traceback :

```
[INFO] loading model...
[INFO] starting video stream...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "real_time_object_detection.py", line 78, in <module>
    label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone help out with this, what changes are to be made elsewhere.

Comment: This means that the object `image` is `None` when the code runs. So when `shape` is called on it, it crashes. Therefore the issue seems to be with how the image is read.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.The issue is solved however. Please let me know if u can comment on the above section